# How to combine ACLs and enable authentication in Squid3 web proxy server?

Tags: authentication, filter, proxy, acl, squid

I'm facing some difficulties while applying a filter to authenticated users in squid3 web proxy server version 3.3.8 .

I already configured squid3 as follows:

- NCSA Authentication

> auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwords
>
> auth_param basic children 5
>
> auth_param basic realm Squid Proxy Web Server
>
> auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
>
> auth_param basic casesensitive on

- Custome ACLs

I created some new ACLs as follows:

> acl group1 src "/etc/squid3/group1_ips.txt" proxy_auth REQUIRED
>
> acl bad_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid3/bad_domains.txt"

where group1_ips.txt is a file containing the list of I IPs of a certain group1 and bad_domains.txt is a file containing the list of domains I want to filter.

- http_access

Now in http_access I made the following:

> http_access deny bad_domains group1
>
> http_access allow all

- My problem is:

Authenticating a list of users via their IP and to prevent them from logging into some web sites. Basically this line of code which does not work.

> acl group1 src "/etc/squid3/group1_ips.txt" proxy_auth REQUIRED

However this line works:

> acl group1 proxy_auth REQUIRED

But I want the group1 ACL to use the src argument.
I tried this also but it did not work:

> acl group1 src "/etc/squid3/group1_ips.txt"
>
> acl group1 proxy_auth REQUIRED

Please how can I solve this: Applying a Filter to authenticated users?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
acl group1 src "/etc/squid3/group1_ips.txt"
acl bad_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid3/bad_domains.txt
acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED

# we require authentication for all users here
http_access deny !auth

# allow all for group1 except of bad_domains
http_access allow !bad_domains group1

# deny if not matched rules above
http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation and there is no reference you can use "src" followed by a file containing IP addresses - every example seems to point to a specific address or network.

Are you sure what you are trying to do is supported?

Source: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

I intended to post this as a comment but I lack the reputation.

Comment: yes using a file containing a list of ips or domains each in a line works very fine. Try it and see.

Comment: Very well. When you say "does not work", what do you mean? Is there an error? Or do the users have access anyway?

Comment: The way I want to it to work is as follows:
-User must authenticate. If authenticated he can start using his browser but he should not access to the filred sites.

With the configuration I posted. browser says cannot connect to proxy

Comment: If the browser says it can't even connect to the proxy, then doesn't that mean the proxy didn't start up correctly? Is there anything on the logs that indicates a misconfiguration or failure to start?

Comment: No !!
If I use it like this:

acl group1 proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access deny bad_domains group1

http_access allow all

It works.

But the problem is I have different groups and the sites i want to filter are not the same for all groups
So I need to apply a filter for each group

Comment: From what I could understand, when you say that proxy_auth is required, you're basically saying that the SRC for that ACL is the list of users. You can't specify two sources. What you need to do instead is do "proxy_auth <list of users>", so as to apply that ACL to that list of users from the proxy.

Comment: acl group1 src "/etc/squid3/group1_ips.txt"
acl group1 proxy_auth REQUIRED

By that supposition, when you do this, you're merely rewriting the first command with the second.